# common answer to a question about a price for alcohol

Tags: phrase-request

What's the common way for the seller to answer a question inquiring about a price for alcohol?

I am especially interested in what preposition would be used right before the container (which is almost always a bottle)

> -- How much is the Red Bull wine?
>
> -- It's 12 dollars **per** a bottle.

Or should it be

> 12 dollars **for** a bottle

or simply

> 12 dollars a bottle

or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask about a rate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98519/how-to-ask-about-a-rate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All three options work and are widely used. But you do need to drop the article if you use 'per':

- 12 dollars per bottle
- 12 dollars for a bottle
- 12 dollars a bottle

Comment: Or just "12 dollars", since we know that wine is normally sold in bottles, it could be understood from the context.